# Google Maps computeRoutes Polyline Decode using Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, google-maps-api-3, google-routes-api

I'm attempting to extract routes from the computeRoutes method from the Google Maps API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/reference/rest/v2/TopLevel/computeRoutes). I'm able to get the correct response each time, which I verify here (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/polylinedecoder), but when I use json.encode and then json.decode(response.body), the encodedPolyline comes back altered because certain escape character sequences are adjusted (two backslashes in my case \). Why is this the case? Should I be using a different method? The original response.body works just fine when I log it into my console, so I'm not sure what the issues is:
//server.js

```
app.post('/api/computeRoutes', async (req, res) => {
      const { origin, destination, travelMode } = req.body;
      const apiKey = process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY;
    
      const [originLat, originLng] = origin.split(',').map(Number);
      const [destinationLat, destinationLng] = destination.split(',').map(Number);
    
      const url = `https://routes.googleapis.com/directions/v2:computeRoutes?key=${apiKey}`;
    
      const data = {
        origin: {
          location: {
            latLng: {
              latitude: originLat, 
              longitude: originLng
            } 
          }
        },
        destination: {
          location: { 
            latLng: { 
              latitude: destinationLat, 
              longitude: destinationLng 
            } 
          }
        },
        travelMode: "DRIVE"
        // travelMode: travelMode.toUpperCase() || 'DRIVING'
      };
    
      const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Goog-FieldMask': 'routes.duration,routes.distanceMeters,routes.polyline.encodedPolyline'
      };
      
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(url, data, { headers });
        console.log(`Server.js Response Data: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
        res.json(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in computeRoutes:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error occurred while fetching routes');
      }
    });
```

//map_service.dart

```
  Future<dynamic> getDirections(String origin, String destination, {String travelMode = 'DRIVING'}) async {
    final url = '$_baseUrl/api/computeRoutes';

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: json.encode({
        'origin': origin,
        'destination': destination,
        'travelMode': travelMode,
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String responseBody = response.body;
      return json.decode(response.body); // Adjust according to your server's response format
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get directions: ${response.body}');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure about your code but indeed encoded polylines are tricky because the backslash is in their character set. Perhaps you can find useful hints in the JavaScript code in the tool embedded in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility which includes an option to "Unescape special characters in the encoded polylines returned in JSON responses" precisely to deal with this problem.